# Generate Passphrase from the data & encrypted data

Tags: encryption, aes, passphrase

right now I'm thinking about how to secure some data inside an Application... Now i have the following problem:

Is it possible to generate the passpharase from a decrypted message and the same message encrypted with AES and the passpharse?

Example:

The decrypted message is : "Hello"

The passpharse is: "you"

And the encrypted message is : "Eat7mV9cX/ncVOiFjdJwIcaE+UO5tt44Zk/kJeSDGyo=" (as base64 encoded)

Comment: I don't know if I get it right. You want to generate the passphrase "you" from the message "Hello". Does the passphrase have to be a word or a sentence?

Comment: that doesnt matter, the question is if it is possible to generate the passphares if the encrypted & decrypted message is available. (in the example the passpharse is just the word "you")

Comment: When you say *generate* did you mean *retrieve*?

Comment: yeah you could say retrieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "known plaintext attack" (not to be confused with a chosen plaintext attack).

There is a known plaintext attack called XSL which some people believe could work on AES, but it is important to point out that even if it did work, it would still take hundreds of trillions of years to break the encryption. (That counts as working in cryptographic terms because it's less than the thousands of trillions of years that brute force would take.)